# Http Function in factory not work in controller when use the "then"

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to call the `http` function of Factory in controller ,it does not work when I use the `.then`
My code is as follows:

module :

`var brandlistmodule = angular.module('newApp`')

factory :

```
brandlistmodule.factory('BrandListFactory',["$http","$routeParams",function($http,$routeParams){
    console.log(2)
    return {
        a: function(response){
            console.log('1');
             return $http.get("/restful_api/category_1/?format=json").then(function(response){
                 console.log('3');
                  return response.data;
             });

        },
        b: function(response){
             return $http.get("/restful_api/category_refer_a/?format=json").then(function(response){
                  return response.data;
             });

        },
        c: function(response){
             return $http.get("/restful_api/brand_test_search/?format=json").then(function(response){
                  result = response.data
                  return result;
             });

        },

    }

}])
```

controller:

```
brandlistmodule.controller('brandlistCtrl', ['BrandListFactory','$scope','$rootScope','$http',function (BrandListFactory,$scope,$rootScope,$http) {
        $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
        $rootScope.category = function(){
         BrandListFactory.a.success(function(data){
             console.log('9');
             $rootScope.category =data 
         });

     };
```

In the console it only can show the "2",if I change the controller as follows ,it will work properly

```
brandlistmodule.controller('brandlistCtrl', ['BrandListFactory','$scope',function (BrandListFactory,$scope) {
    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
   BrandListFactory.BrandCategoryList()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is you're calling Then() inside the factory...so what you can do is :

1 - NO CALLING THEN .. but RETURN ALL YOUR $http request to the caller of the Factory .. like:

```
brandlistmodule.factory('BrandListFactory',["$http","$routeParams",function($http,$routeParams){
    console.log(2)
    return {
        a: function(response){
            console.log('1');
             return $http.get("/restful_api/category_1/?format=json");

        },
        b: function(response){
             return $http.get("/restful_api/category_refer_a/?format=json");

        },
        c: function(response){
             return $http.get("/restful_api/brand_test_search/?format=json");

        },

    }

}])
```

2- use $q and make by yourself the asyncron chain .. like:

```
brandlistmodule.factory('BrandListFactory',["$http","$routeParams","$q",function($http,$routeParams,$q){
    console.log(2)
    return {
        a: function(response){
var deferred = $q.defer();
            console.log('1');
             return $http.get("/restful_api/category_1/?format=json").then(function(response){
                 console.log('3');
                 deferred.resolve( response.data);
             }).catch(function(err){
deferred.reject(err);
});

return deffered.promise;

        } 
// and same for others
    }

}])
```

Comment: I'm so appreciate for your Patient explanation,I have solved the problem with your help .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to creat a Service which is responsible for all of your http calls something like this

```
.service('HttpService', ['$rootScope', '$http', 'Ls', 'CommonService', 'DateService', function ($rootScope, $http, Ls, CommonService, DateService) {
        return {
            CallService: function (url, callback) {                   
                $http.get(url)
                    .success(function (data, status) {                            
                        callback(data, status);
                    }).error(function (data, status) {
                        callback(data, status);
                    });                 
            } 
        }
    });
```

If you pass the parameter callback into the `HttpService.CallService` then you can call the callback in the `success` or `error` function of the `http.get` call.

For example in the Controller you can do

```
    HttpService.CallService('/restful_api/category_refer_a/?format=json', function (data) {
                        console.log(data)
                        //do something with your data

    });
```

So in your example you could do:

```
 $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
             HttpService.CallService('/restful_api/category_refer_a/?format=json', function (data) {
                            console.log('9');
                 $rootScope.category =data 

        });
});
```

or you simply change your calls to

```
b: function(callback){
             return $http.get("/restful_api/category_refer_a/?format=json").then(function(response){
                  callback(response.data);
             });

        },
```

and

```
BrandListFactory.b(function(data){
             console.log('9');
             $rootScope.category =data 
         });
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Yes,You tell me why It can't work :In the factory you prefer to use  "return" other than "then",if You insist on "then",you should use $q to solve possible asyncron problem ,Is it right ?